# How do you create custom prompts for different users in a bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I am using a CentOS VM. I would like to make the prompt for a regular user to be:

```
[user@servername active directory]$
```

I would like the prompt for a root user to be:

```
[root@servername active directory]#
```

I tried using an if/else statement in the *.bashrc* file (although I have no experience programming in C-based languages):

```
if [\u == "root"]; then
    export PS1="\e[1;33m[\u@\h \w]\# \e[m"
else
    export PS1="\e[1;33m[\u@\h \w]\$ \e[m"
fi
```

It seems to work except for the fact that the dollar sign at the end of the prompt does not change to a pound -# sign when I switch to a root user.

Comment: If I should be posting this on another more relevant forum, please let me know. I would hate to be banned from posting questions since I'm already treading on thin ice with stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

There are different approaches to customize the Bash Prompt. For user-specific configuration edit, **~/.bashrc** and add your customization below the line '# User specific aliases and functions'

This example:

```
PS1='\u@\H:\w\$ '
```

will result in the following prompt:

```
user@hostname.domain.tld:/working/directory$
```

If you prefer a colorful prompt, try:

```
PS1='\[\033[02;32m\]\u@\H:\[\033[02;34m\]\w\$\[\033[00m\] '
```

You can find color codes [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html).

**System-wide Configuration**

```
# [ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \w]\\$ "
   PS1='\u@\H:\w\$ '
```

To create custom prompts for different users I would like you to have a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305052/changing-behavior-of-bash-prompt-when-functioning-as-root).

Comment: Thanks! That helped!

Answer (score 2):

The `\$` directive already knows that it is supposed to display "#" for the root user. See [Controlling the Prompt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt) in the bash manual.

For that prompt to be set for every user, add to **/etc/bash.bashrc**

```
PS1='\[\e[1;33m\][\u@\h \w]\$ \[\e[m\]"\'
```

Remember to put `\[` and `\]` around the "invisible" color codes, otherwise you'll see odd effects when editing your command line.

Comment: It's good to know that I don't have to use \# for root. It's all working now!